# Always include a service in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a `cookie-service` which is responsible for showing a cookie banner to accept site cookies. It is also used for setting and getting cookies if the user accepted them.

My issue is that if I do not include the service in any component, the cookie banner also does not show. I also tried different methods to provide it in the module but that didn't work either. Is there a way to include a service in angular even if it's not explicitly included in any component.

> Update
>
> I tried to register the service as suggested, however the console log
> still won't show.

**shared module**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  exports: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
  providers: [
    CookieService,
    // ...
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

**service**

changed the injectable part

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class CookieService { 
  constructor() {
    console.log('cookie service is alive');
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: What version of angular are you using? you can either provide the service in root without explicitly stating where it will be provided or you provide it only in the component that you intend to use it. Also, A sample code of what you are trying to do will help understand your problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT

As a workaround, create a directive and use it on the root component of your application. Inject your service there and you are done. You could also move the logic from your service into that directive. This way you are not polluting your components with useless injections.

Or, as another user suggested, just inject it into the root component and be done with it(but be sure to leave a comment about WHY you are just injecting something there and then not use it)

#### ORIGINAL

My guess is that your service is getting tree-shaken by Webpack. To prevent this, delete the `providedIn` from the `@Injectable` decorator, and put your service class into the `providers` array of your `@NgModule`.

Here are the relevant parts from the documentation:

> Registering the provider in the @Injectable() metadata also allows Angular to optimize an app by removing the service from the compiled application if it isn't used, a process known as tree-shaking.

> Using the @Injectable() providedIn property is preferable to the @NgModule() providers array because with @Injectable() providedIn, optimization tools can perform tree-shaking, which removes services that your application isn't using and results in smaller bundle sizes.

Comment: This is similar to what i tried. I update my question, do you have any idea why its not running the constructor?

Comment: My guess is that while the service is NOT tree shaken, the actual instance is NOT created until it is needed. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Just inject it to your `AppComponent`. This should look like this:

```
    export class AppComponent {
        constructor(cookieService: CookieService) { }
        // ...
    }
```